# What are the best ways to localise a cell phone (obtain its longitude and its latitude) from a website?

Tags: java, c#, android, swift, geolocation

I am working on a project in which one I have to localise the cell phone of some employees, with their permission, for sure.  The goal of this project is to localise them and to calculate their distance from a certain place. Once their distance calculated, I will use a website who will show me in red those who are, by example, at more than 50 kilometers. I would like to know what are the best ways to do it.

Those are the solutions I envisioned :

1. Using Google Latitude API to localise a cellphone from a Google account, but it was retired in August 9th, 2013.
2. Build an Android and an Apple application that will run in background with a new Thread to send the position of the cell phone in a distant database every 10 minutes. If this is a good solution, what software would you advise me to use to developp a multi-platform application (Android and IOS) ?
3. Developp a website instead of an application that will send the geographical coordinates of the cell phone in a distant database. Maybe I could use Geolocation API ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API ) and an interval to refresh the page avery 10 minutes. But, when the user will close the tab or the Internet application, it won't work anymore.

I am now trying to better understand how the localisation system of Google works (Find your phone https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm&hl=fr ). Maybe this could help me find a good solution, but I have not found anything at this time.

I am a beginner programmer. The languages I know for the website are Html, Asp.net (C#), PHP, Javascript, JQuery and a little bit Angular.

I also use MySql, Java and Python. I have still not learned Swift (advices appreciated :) ).

I am also opened to other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a "best way" for something like that.

You will need:

- a backend service + Database
- Mobile app with a lot of constraints(especially on iOS)
- A frontend to display all these data on a website.

There is a lot of "uber like" tutorials using parse.com or firebase with native mobile apps. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at this.